# VBA Excel Collections method

Tags: excel, vba

I am new in vba please help me to solve the following problem using by Collections.

I want name of student from below data where student is from USA or England that study maths or history using Collections

```
Student             Country       Subject          Mark
Norris Reid         England        Maths            23
Merry Guider        France         Bio              48
Karly Manzella      USA            History          55
Brett Keltner       Germany        Geography        62
Jasmin Legg         USA            French           50
Mana Marlett        Australia      Bio              61
Renaldo Deems       USA            Geography        24
Kandance Kurt       SA             Geography        58
Dusty More          England        Bio              45
Denise Mathew       France         Geography        78
Classie Leatherman  Ireland        Bio              76
Jerilyn Sidner      Spain          French           71
```

Comment: Why would you want to use collections? Why don't you take an autofilter? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for your kind support...!

but as i mentioned i am new in this field so your code is bit 
complicate to me so i have tried at my end.

Sub collection_example()
Dim col As New Collection
Dim C As Range
Sheets("BBB").Range("a2").Select
For Each C In Sheets("BBB").Range("A2:A13")
If (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "England" Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "USA") 
And (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Maths" Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "History") Then
col.Add C.Value, CStr(C.Value)
End If
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next C
End Sub

Comment: Did you try the code I posted? Did it work? Then try to understand and it might be more helpful than your code you posted in the comments. BTW, you can edit your post and add it there.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, to give you something to think about. First [create a class modul](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-class-modules/#Creating_a_Simple_Class_Module)e, name it StudentLine and put the following code into it

```
Option Explicit
Dim m_student As String
Dim m_country As String
Dim m_subject As String
Dim m_mark As Long

    Property Let student(nVal As String)
        m_student = nVal
    End Property

    Property Get student() As String
        student = m_student
    End Property

    Property Let country(nVal As String)
        m_country = nVal
    End Property

    Property Get country() As String
        country = m_country
    End Property
    Property Let subject(nVal As String)
        m_subject = nVal
    End Property

    Property Get subject() As String
        subject = m_subject
    End Property
    Property Let mark(nVal As Long)
        m_mark = nVal
    End Property

    Property Get mark() As Long
        mark = m_mark
    End Property
```

Then [create a normal module](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-macro-create/#Step_5Create_a_Module) and put the following code into it

```
Option Explicit

Sub ColTest()

Const ENGLAND = "ENGLAND"
Const USA = "USA"
Const MATHS = "MATHS"
Const HISTORY = "HISTORY"
Const COL_NAME = 1
Const COL_COUNTRY = 2
Const COL_SUBJECT = 3
Const COL_MARK = 4

Dim col As New Collection
Dim rg As Range
Dim line As StudentLine
Dim i As Long
Dim country As String
Dim subject As String


    Set rg = Range("A2:E13")
    Dim sngRow As Range
    Dim vdat As Variant

    vdat = rg

    For i = LBound(vdat) To UBound(vdat)
        country = UCase(vdat(i, COL_COUNTRY))
        subject = UCase(vdat(i, COL_SUBJECT))
        If country = ENGLAND Or country = USA Then
            If subject = MATHS Or subject = HISTORY Then
                Set line = New StudentLine
                With line
                    .student = vdat(i, COL_NAME)
                    .country = vdat(i, COL_COUNTRY)
                    .subject = vdat(i, COL_SUBJECT)
                    .mark = vdat(i, COL_MARK)
                End With
                col.Add line
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    For i = 1 To col.Count
        Debug.Print col.Item(i).student, col.Item(i).country, col.Item(i).subject, col.Item(i).mark
    Next i

End Sub
```

The asumption is that the above data is in range A1:D13 including header. 
[image]

The collection contains the data you requested.

Comment: So Far i did tried this code to add required data using collection. Is it OK.
Sub clecsn()
Dim col As New Collection
Dim C As Range
Sheets("BBB").Range("a2").Select
For Each C In Sheets("BBB").Range("A2:A13")
If (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "England" Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "USA") And (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Maths" Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "History") Then
col.add C.Value, CStr(C.Value)
End If
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next C
End Sub

Comment: I will certainly not copy this `unformatted` code from the comment and try it or even have a look at it. If you have questions to the code I posted feel free to ask but I would recommend to try my code in the first place instead of ignoring my post and asking if your code is ok?